# How do I compare two classifiers in Weka using the Paired T-test

Tags: machine-learning, weka, statistics

In Weka I can go to the experimenter.  In the set-up I can load in an .arff file, and get weka to create a classifier (i.e. J48), then I can run it and then finally I can go to the analyze tab.  In this tab it gives me an option to 'testing with Paired T-Test' but I cannot figure out how to create a second classifier (i.e. J48 unpruned) and do a T-Test on the two results.

Google does not lead me to any tutorial or answers.

How can I get Weka to do a T-Test on the results of two different classifiers, made from the same data?

Comment: http://fiji.sc/Advanced_Weka_Segmentation_-_How_to_compare_classifiers Does this help?

Comment: That helps but I can't find out how it gives t-value or p-values.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the steps in http://fiji.sc/Advanced_Weka_Segmentation_-_How_to_compare_classifiers.

In this [screenshot](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/File%3aScreenshot-AWS-tutorial-percentage-correct-test.png), the author is setting the significance level to be **0.05**. In my understanding, in such a test, you always compare with a baseline classifier (here it is the NaiveBayes), the output uses the annotation v or * to indicate that a speciﬁc result is statistically better (v) or worse (*) than the baseline scheme at the signiﬁcance level speciﬁed (currently 0.05). It might not be the one you expected though.